# Javascript deep object filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, utility

I am building deepFilterObject.js utility function. Tried many, none of them work.
My object before the filter is something like this:

```
{
  userId: '6501747e258044dcfcf8c765',
  name: 'Morning workout',
  exercises: [
    { exercise: 'Oblique Crunch', sets: [Array] },
    { exercise: 'Chest Fly (Dumbbell)', sets: [Array] },
    { exercise: 'Jump Squat', sets: [Array] }
  ],
  metadata: {
    evaluation: null,
    type: 'realtime',
    copy: false,
    note: 'This is a note. (optional)',
    estimatedDurationMinutes: 60,
    description: 'Some description. (optional)',
    dates: {
      scheduled: 'Tue Aug 08 2023 10:55:56',
      completed: null,
      creation: 'Tue Aug 01 2023 12:51:35'
    },
    access: {
      authorId: 'objectId',
      type: 'public/private (ENUM)',
      comments: [Array],
      copies: 0
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my function call:

```
const filteredBody = deepFilterObject(object, 'name', 'exercises', 'metadata.evaluation', 'metadata.access.type');
```

I expect something like this object as a result:

```
{
  userId: '6501747e258044dcfcf8c765',
  name: 'Morning workout',
  exercises: [
    { exercise: 'Oblique Crunch', sets: [Array] },
    { exercise: 'Chest Fly (Dumbbell)', sets: [Array] },
    { exercise: 'Jump Squat', sets: [Array] }
  ],
  metadata: {
    evaluation: null,
    access: {
      type: 'public/private (ENUM)',
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my code for my utility, which I import into my controller as "deepFilterObject":

```
function createObjectFromNestedArray(inputArray, sourceObject) {
  // Base case: If the input array is empty, return the sourceObject.
  if (inputArray.length === 0) {
    return sourceObject;
  }

  // Get the current key from the inputArray.
  const [currentKey, ...remainingKeys] = inputArray[0];

  // Check if the current key exists in the sourceObject.
  if (sourceObject.hasOwnProperty(currentKey)) {
    // If it exists, recursively call the function with the remaining keys and the existing object.
    sourceObject[currentKey] = createObjectFromNestedArray(remainingKeys, sourceObject[currentKey]);
  } else {
    // If it doesn't exist, create a new object and attach it.
    sourceObject[currentKey] = {};

    // Recursively call the function with the remaining keys and the newly created object.
    sourceObject[currentKey] = createObjectFromNestedArray(remainingKeys, sourceObject[currentKey]);
  }

  // Return the modified sourceObject.
  return sourceObject;
}

function deepFilterObject(obj, ...allowedFields) {
  console.log(obj);
  //   const newObj = {};
  //   Object.keys(obj).forEach(el => {
  //     if (allowedFields.includes(el)) newObj[el] = obj[el];
  //   });

  const deepAllowedFields = allowedFields
    .filter(allowedField => allowedField.split('.').length > 1)
    .map(allowedField => allowedField.split('.'));

  const finalObj = createObjectFromNestedArray(deepAllowedFields, obj);
  //   console.log(finalObj);

  //   return newObj;
}

module.exports = deepFilterObject;
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you've shown the original object and your function and what you want the output to be, but what does it produce currently? If you could edit your question and turn your code into a runnable snippet, that would really improve the clarity of your question and make it much easier for anyone trying to help you. Click the button in the toolbar that looks like `[<>]` to add a code snippet to your question.

Comment: `inputArray[0]` you are accessing just the first item and ignore the other

Comment: Pointer: create two functions (`get(obj, "prop.subProp")`, `set(obj, "prop.subProp", value)`) that handle the dot notation access (in strings), and then simply loop the filter variables and create/return a new object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most easy way is to copy each path in order from source to a new object, creating the path in new object if it's missing

```
function deepFilterObject(obj, ...paths) {
    let result = {};
    for (let s of paths) {
        let from = obj, to = result;
        let path = s.split('.');
        let prop = path.pop();
        for (let p of path) {
            to = (to[p] ??= {});
            from = from[p];
        }
        to[prop] = from[prop];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: best and elegant way to solve, but please include userId in object manually as question asker want this to.

Answer (score 1):

Loop the paths and go recursive if the path is multi-level:

```js
function deepFilterObject(obj, ...props){

  const filter = (obj, out, p, idx = 0) => {
      const k = p[idx];
      idx  === p.length - 1 ? out[k] = obj[k] :filter(obj[k], out[k] ??= {}, p, idx + 1);
  };
  
  const out = {};
  for(const p of props){
    p in obj ? out[p] = obj[p] : filter(obj, out, p.split('.'));
  }
  return out;

}

const filteredBody = deepFilterObject(obj, 'name', 'exercises', 'metadata.evaluation', 'metadata.access.type');

$pre.innerText = JSON.stringify(filteredBody, null, 4);
```

```html
<script>
const obj ={
  userId: '6501747e258044dcfcf8c765',
  name: 'Morning workout',
  exercises: [
    { exercise: 'Oblique Crunch', sets: [Array] },
    { exercise: 'Chest Fly (Dumbbell)', sets: [Array] },
    { exercise: 'Jump Squat', sets: [Array] }
  ],
  metadata: {
    evaluation: null,
    type: 'realtime',
    copy: false,
    note: 'This is a note. (optional)',
    estimatedDurationMinutes: 60,
    description: 'Some description. (optional)',
    dates: {
      scheduled: 'Tue Aug 08 2023 10:55:56',
      completed: null,
      creation: 'Tue Aug 01 2023 12:51:35'
    },
    access: {
      authorId: 'objectId',
      type: 'public/private (ENUM)',
      comments: [Array],
      copies: 0
    }
  }
}
</script>
<pre id="$pre"></pre>
```

And a benchmark:

```
Cycles: 1000000 / Chrome/116
--------------------------------------------------------
Alexander;   172/min  1.0x  183  186  181  172  177  187
Dimava       183/min  1.1x  187  187  211  198  199  183
Konrad       534/min  3.1x  556  534  560  577  534  567
--------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark
```

```html
<script benchmark="1000000">

    const obj ={
      userId: '6501747e258044dcfcf8c765',
      name: 'Morning workout',
      exercises: [
        { exercise: 'Oblique Crunch', sets: [Array] },
        { exercise: 'Chest Fly (Dumbbell)', sets: [Array] },
        { exercise: 'Jump Squat', sets: [Array] }
      ],
      metadata: {
        evaluation: null,
        type: 'realtime',
        copy: false,
        note: 'This is a note. (optional)',
        estimatedDurationMinutes: 60,
        description: 'Some description. (optional)',
        dates: {
          scheduled: 'Tue Aug 08 2023 10:55:56',
          completed: null,
          creation: 'Tue Aug 01 2023 12:51:35'
        },
        access: {
          authorId: 'objectId',
          type: 'public/private (ENUM)',
          comments: [Array],
          copies: 0
        }
      }
    }
    
    // @benchmark Konrad
    function deepFilterObject3(object, ...paths) {
  // parse paths to get the path object
  const pathObject = preparePathObject(paths)
  
  // recursive function
  function filterObject(obj, path) {
    const newObject = {}
    // for each entry in the path object
    for (const [key, subPath] of Object.entries(path)) {
      // get sub object from the original object
      const subObj = obj[key]
      // if the sub object is an object, but not null or array
      if (typeof subObj === 'object' && subObj !== null && !Array.isArray(subObj)) {
        // run recursion
        newObject[key] = filterObject(subObj, subPath)
      } else {
        // else assign the object to the new object
        newObject[key] = subObj
      }
    }
    
    return newObject
  }
  
  return filterObject(object, pathObject)
}

// creates nested path object
function preparePathObject(paths) {
  const obj = {}
  for (const path of paths) {
    const keys = path.split('.')
    let current = obj
    for (const key of keys) {
      if (!(key in current)) {
        current[key] = {}
      }
      current = current[key]
    }
  }
  return obj
}
// @run
 deepFilterObject3(obj, 'name', 'exercises', 'metadata.evaluation', 'metadata.access.type');   
    // @benchmark Dimava
    function deepFilterObject2(obj, ...paths) {
    let result = {};
    for (let s of paths) {
        let from = obj, to = result;
        let path = s.split('.');
        let prop = path.pop();
        for (let p of path) {
            to = (to[p] ??= {});
            from = from[p];
        }
        to[prop] = from[prop];
    }
    return result;
    } 
    
    //@run
     deepFilterObject2(obj, 'name', 'exercises', 'metadata.evaluation', 'metadata.access.type');
    
    // @benchmark Alexander;


function deepFilterObject(obj, ...props){

  const filter = (obj, out, p, idx = 0) => {
      const k = p[idx];
      idx  === p.length - 1 ? out[k] = obj[k] :filter(obj[k], out[k] ??= {}, p, idx + 1);
  };
  
  const out = {};
  for(const p of props){
    p in obj ? out[p] = obj[p] : filter(obj, out, p.split('.'));
  }
  return out;

}
    //@run;

    deepFilterObject(obj, 'name', 'exercises', 'metadata.evaluation', 'metadata.access.type');

</script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do it like this:

```js
const object = {
  userId: '6501747e258044dcfcf8c765',
  name: 'Morning workout',
  exercises: [
    { exercise: 'Oblique Crunch', sets: [Array] },
    { exercise: 'Chest Fly (Dumbbell)', sets: [Array] },
    { exercise: 'Jump Squat', sets: [Array] }
  ],
  metadata: {
    evaluation: null,
    type: 'realtime',
    copy: false,
    note: 'This is a note. (optional)',
    estimatedDurationMinutes: 60,
    description: 'Some description. (optional)',
    dates: {
      scheduled: 'Tue Aug 08 2023 10:55:56',
      completed: null,
      creation: 'Tue Aug 01 2023 12:51:35'
    },
    access: {
      authorId: 'objectId',
      type: 'public/private (ENUM)',
      comments: [Array],
      copies: 0
    }
  }
}

const filteredBody = deepFilterObject(object, 'name', 'exercises', 'metadata.evaluation', 'metadata.access.type');

document.write(`<pre>${JSON.stringify(filteredBody, null, 4)}</pre>`)

function deepFilterObject(object, ...paths) {
  // parse paths to get the path object
  const pathObject = preparePathObject(paths)
  
  // recursive function
  function filterObject(obj, path) {
    const newObject = {}
    // for each entry in the path object
    for (const [key, subPath] of Object.entries(path)) {
      // get sub object from the original object
      const subObj = obj[key]
      // if the sub object is an object, but not null or array
      if (typeof subObj === 'object' && subObj !== null && !Array.isArray(subObj)) {
        // run recursion
        newObject[key] = filterObject(subObj, subPath)
      } else {
        // else assign the object to the new object
        newObject[key] = subObj
      }
    }
    
    return newObject
  }
  
  return filterObject(object, pathObject)
}

// creates nested path object
function preparePathObject(paths) {
  const obj = {}
  for (const path of paths) {
    const keys = path.split('.')
    let current = obj
    for (const key of keys) {
      if (!(key in current)) {
        current[key] = {}
      }
      current = current[key]
    }
  }
  return obj
}
```